# How use htaccess for seo friendly url with subdomains?

Tags: .htaccess

This is my htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com(.*)
RewriteRule .* inside.php?tx=%1&filter=%2
```

This url: hello.mydomain.com goes to www.mydomain.com/inside.php?tx=hello
Thats correct.

Now i need this url   hello.mydomain.com/bye/  goes to www.mydomain.com/inside.php?tx=hello&filter=bye, but don't work. Only goes to www.mydomain.com/inside.php?tx=hello

This htaccess is ignoring the second variable (bye). Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` only contains the host name (`hello.mydomain.com`), so your second backreference doesn't have anything in it. Changing your `RewriteRule` to the following should give the behaviour you're expecting:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*) inside.php?tx=%1&filter=$1
```

**Edit:** To correct the situation described in your comment, the entire ruleset should be as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*) inside.php?tx=%1&filter=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for yous answers
I change the rewriterule to this:
RewriteRule ^([^/]*) inside.php?tx=%1&filter=$1 
but now this url: hello.mydomain.com/bye/ goes to:
www.mydomain.com/inside.php?tx=hello&filter=inside.php